# unable to replace values with the replace command in python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to make a column named 'TitleGroup' which will have groups of people which will group the similar titles with a number

```
traindf['Title'] = traindf['Name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(',')[1].split('.')[0])
traindf['TitleGroup'] = 0
traindf['TitleGroup'] = traindf['Title'].replace(['Mrs','Miss','Mme','Ms','Lady','Mlle','the Countess','Dona'], 'female', regex  = True)
traindf['TitleGroup'] = traindf['Title'].replace(['Sir','Don','Rev','Mr',],'male', regex = True)
#traindf['TitleGroup'] = traindf['Title'].replace(['Col','Dr','Col','Capt','Major','Jonkheer','Master'],'Special', regex = True)
#traindf['TitleGroup'] = traindf['Title'].map({'male':1, 'female':0, 'Special':2})
traindf.head()
```

[image]

1.The program is outputting few Titles right but look at the 2nd row 'Mrs' is getting outputted as 'males'? Title with 'Mrs' should be replaced with 'female' but it does not.

2.uncommenting the 5th line it displays the TitleGroup with same names as Title.

3.Making regex as False outputs the same result as 2nd point.

4.Uncommenting the 6th line results in TitleGroup being all NaN

Even using .loc says I can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the python documentation for the [replace method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), the method will :

> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new.

So, when you make the first replacement (`traindf['Title'].replace(['Mrs','Miss','Mme','Ms','Lady','Mlle','the Countess','Dona'], 'female', regex  = True)`) you do not change the content of the `traindf['Title']`, but you put result in your `traindf['TitleGroup']` field. So every Mrs, Miss... in the `traindf['Title']` is still there.

Then, when you do the second replacement : `traindf['Title'].replace(['Sir','Don','Rev','Mr',],'male', regex=True)`, there are still some 'Mrs' in the `traindf['Title']`, and in 'Mrs', there is 'Mr' ^_^, so the `replace` method will find some 'Mr' to replace with 'male', and your 'Mrs' will become 'males'

If you want to avoid such problems, you can chain the replace calls like this :

```
traindf['TitleGroup'] = traindf['Title'].replace(
    ['Mrs','Miss','Mme','Ms','Lady','Mlle','the Countess','Dona'],
    'female', 
    regex=True
).replace(['Sir','Don','Rev','Mr',],'male', regex = True)
```

this way, the resulting string will be store once in the `traindf['TitleGroup']` and all the replacement will be done.

Comment: It worked! but mapping is throwing me NaNs again? I know I can directly use the numbers instead of male, female and special. but from my understanding map function should have worked. right?

Comment: @Pseudo I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve with your numbers, if you need to count the occurences of each kind, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#counter-objects) objects

Comment: I'm trying to convert them in numbers so that I can use it on my machine learning model.